# Enabling and Disabling Save button on a GWT page

Tags: javascript, events, gwt, textbox, dom-events

The application I am working on has pages of setup data with lots of textboxes; each page having a save button.  I have defined most of the pages as a *.ui.xml file and used the GWT 2.0 UI binding.

I would like to add a save button which is disabled `onload` and is only enabled after a user modifies the data into one of the textboxes.

I know I can register an event handler against each element on the page to enable the button, but I  wanted a more elegant solution.  Ideally, I would like to define a button that "listens" to events on the page and changes itself.  Is this possible in GWT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also add the change event to your whole containing widget using `addDomHandler`

```
public class SetupDataPage extends Composite{

  // Binder stuff  

  // Button from the binder
  @UiField Button saveBtn;

  public SetupDataPage(){
        addDomHandler(new ChangeHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                saveBtn.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }, ChangeEvent.getType());
  }
}
```

**Beware** This will trigger the event for all textboxes in SetupDataPage. On the other side it might not work for some specific widgets. I know it works for GWT's textbox, checkbox, listbox...

Comment: This worked well for us.  Is there any performance issues on load of a page with a domHandler?

Comment: @Tihom We haven't noticed any but no advanced performance tests have been done.

Comment: This mostly works.  The exception we found is in IE if the page has a listbox.  Changing the value in the listbox in IE doesn't trigger a ChangeEvent on the dom.  I had to add an explicit change handler on the listbox to make it work

Answer (score 2):

Check out the GWT articles on MVP
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2.html

Specifically the part on Events and the Event Bus.

Also look at this http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/8b0ae5eaf84d8bc2?hide_quotes=no

Comment: +1 The video linked in that Groups thread is solid gold. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuhR18-EdM

Answer (score 1):

You can work out a very simple solution to this.

1. Put all your editable controls in a HTMLPanel (or any other panel if you wish)
2. Have a ui:field reference to this HTMLPanel in the accompanying java file.
3. Soon after you make a call to initWidget in your java class, iterate through all the child widgets of HTMLPanel and register a ChangeHandler on each input widget.

Pseudo Code:

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < hTMLPanel.getWidgetCount( ); i++ )
    {
        Widget widget = hTMLPanel.getWidget( i );

        if ( widget instanceof HasChangeHandlers )
            ((HasChangeHandlers)widget).addChangeHandler( <Your Change Handler to enable save>);
    }
```

You can make this recursive if you have nested widgets.

Comment: I'd just like to add that you should define the `ChangeHandler` before entering the loop and then just reuse it - no need to create/instantiate it for every element.

Comment: the problem with change handlers is that they are executed on "focus lost" event. so you need to type a value in a text box, then use TAB key or click somewhere, then your handler will be executed. moreover, this "value change" event will block "mouse click". e.g. type a value in a text field, then click some "update" button. your "change" handler will be executed, but your mouse click handler won't be.

Answer (score 1):

DOM Handler is better and will perform faster..