# GWT domHandler not working for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, events, gwt, listbox

I added a domHandler for changeEvents.  Following the answer here: [Enabling and Disabling Save button on a GWT page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098694/enabling-and-disabling-save-button-on-a-gwt-page)

This works for listboxes in Chrome and Firefox but doesn't work for IE8.

Does anybody have any recommendations?  I rather not individually handle each textbox and listbox on our page.  I also rather not iterate through each widget on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, even though [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents-h3) say it should do, [Internet Explorer does not bubble up the DOM with the onChange event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Handling each widgets, ever individually or by iterating, seems to be the only option.